# How to stock in an Array the points of a Dice? java

Tags: java, arrays, dice

My aim is to stock how many times a dice has faced a number between 1 and 6 for 10 throws.

It should be something like:

> 1 = 3 time(s)
>
> 2 = 4 time(s)
>
> 3 = 0 time(s)
>
> 4 = 1 time(s)
>
> 5= 1 time(s)
>
> 6 = 1 time(s)
>
> Total = 10 times (or throws)

I've Written so far this code

```
    int final FACES = 6;
    int final THROWS = 10;
    int nbTimes[] = new int[FACES];
    int Face;


    ...


    for(int thr = 1; thr < THROWS ; thr++){
        Face = throwDice();
        if (Face == Face)
        nbTimes[Face] +=1;
    }
```

Where `throwDice()` gives me a random number between 1 and 6. I have this already done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line will always return `true` and is redundant:

```
if (Face == Face)
```

If you'll remove this line (and its predecessor) it'll work fine (as well):

```
...

...
int final FACES = 6;
int final THROWS = 10;
int nbTimes[] = new int[FACES];
int Face;

...

for(int thr = 0; thr < THROWS ; thr++){ // int thr = 0 !!! (if you want 10 throws)
    nbTimes[throwDice()] += 1;
}
```

Comment: This solves my problem but created another: Sometimes it works while compiling and sometimes it throws: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6`

Comment: It means that the method `throwDice()` returns a (potential) value: 6, and the array `nbTimes` has only 6 items: `nbTimes[0], ..., nbTimes[5]` Trying to access `nbTimes[6]` means the 7th element!

Comment: @Sandra its probably because your `throwDice()` return value from 1 to 6 and array index start from 0, so you can just go with   `nbTimes[throwDice() - 1] += 1;`